# NULL pointer using hashmap

Tags: java, android

Can someone please tell my why I'm getting a `null pointer exception` with this code? In my `Nutrition` class, I implement a `hash map`:

```
public class Nutrition implements Serializable{

private final String TAG = Nutrition.class.getSimpleName();
//class variables
    ...

//hash map declaration
HashMap<String, String> nutrition; 

public Nutrition(JSONObject jo) throws JSONException{

    //create hash map
    this.nutrition = new HashMap<String, String>(); 



    //place data in hashmap
    this.serving_size = jo.optString("serving_size");
    nutrition.put("serving_size", serving_size); 
    Log.i(TAG, serving_size + " : Serving Size");
           ....
    }
   //method to get hashmap
   public HashMap<String, String> getHashMap(){
    return nutrition; 
}
```

Then in another class, I call `getHashMap()` and I get a `null pointer`:

```
//nutrition item
    Nutrition nutritionInfo  = dish.getNutrition();
    nutInfo = nutritionInfo.getHashMap();
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix it?

Comment: Well presumably either `dish` is null, or `dish.getNutrition()` is returning null. But you haven't told us anything about either of those, which doesn't help...

Comment: Could we get a stacktrace showing exactly which line causes the NPE?

Comment: At what line do you get nullpointer exception ? That would tell you which reference is null and you are calling a method on a reference pointing to null which is causing NullPointerException

Comment: I get the NPE at line 43, which is the ` nutInfo = nutritionInfo.getHashMap(); `

Comment: I and I know that a `null` value is the reason for the NPE, I'm asking why I'm getting a NPE when I've added value to the hashmap.

Comment: @BlaineOmega it has nothing to do with the hashmap. You get a NPE because `nutritionInfo` is null.

Comment: Thank you @mattb! You're answer makes perfect sense and you solved the problem. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second line will throw an NPE if dish.getNutrition() returns null.

```
Nutrition nutritionInfo  = dish.getNutrition();
nutInfo = nutritionInfo.getHashMap();
```

Since you haven't shown us the code in the Dish class, I would assume it occurs here.